# Raspberry Pi 3B+ no wifi interfaces when setting up for first time

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I have followed the instructions to create my SD card and boot it on my Pi. When creating the SD card I have added the ssh and wpa_supplicant files. During the initial installation at no time am I asked to enter the wifi country. When system is booted it states "no wireless interfaces found". I then go to Raspberry Pi Configuration to enter country but the box is dimmed and I am unable to change it.

I then did sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

This showed me that the information I had entered into the wpa_supplicant.conf when creating the SD card was there.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid="xxxxxx"
    psk="xxxxxx"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

This did not solve problem so did further reading and on another post found a different content fo the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB

network={
    ssid=" 2.4GHz WiFi xxxxxx"
    psk="2.4GHz WPA/WPA2 xxxxxx"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Again this has not worked and I am still getting "no wireless interfaces found"

I have a connection when using Ethernet cable.

It appears that the Country Code for wifi must be entered, is there any other way to enter this?

Comment: if the content looks exactly like you posted, then that could be the problem ... update_config=1 should be on a line by itself, as well as `country=GB` on its own line, and the `network={ .... }` should be over several lines

Comment: Since you can  login on wired interface, I would suggest clearing out the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file, and running `raspi-config` - setting up wifi credentials through that - then see how it has created `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` for future reference

Comment: You can set the language in ```/etc/wpa-supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf``` with ```country=DE```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this command: `ip -br addr`.

Comment: If you had answered the Location etc questions on initial boot the country code should be set. You can re-run setup with `sudo piwiz`

Comment: Did you check below things - especially the wpa-supplicant service?

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestions to track down WIFI issues on raspbian stretch

If WPA2 is used, we need to check for wpa_supplicant service.

You can check the config `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf`

```
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="KBBL"
    psk="abcdef01234567890123456789"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

You can run `systemctl | grep wpa` to see if a wpa-supplicant service is running:

```
  wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service     loaded active running   WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
```

You can run `sudo iwconfig wlan0` to see the current wifi status:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"KBBL RXTX"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.58 GHz  Access Point: 24:65:11:89:84:79   
      Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

You can run `sudo ifconfig wlan0` to see if an IP Addr has been assigned to the wifi interface:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.178.86  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
    ether b8:27:eb:0c:d8:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 8  bytes 1842 (1.7 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 11  bytes 1601 (1.5 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: There will be no such file on a normal system

Comment: @Milliways Could you please specify in more detail?

Comment: There is NO `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` on a normal system, although you can create one. It is poor advice.

Comment: The wlan0 extension makes sure that the correct interface is setup. Actually it works with the standard file as well if you don’t have multiple WiFi interfaces.